# How to display an HTML String in a eclipse (on user interface NOT in Browser)?

Tags: java, html, string, swing, jframe

That's the way I tried. It did not work as I can see `.src/fil...` in the user interface. I want to display the text from the HTML file.

```
public class NewWindow {

private static String file = "./src/file.html";
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel(file);
NewWindow(){
    label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
    label.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,25));
    frame.add(label);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.setSize(420, 420);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: We need to be constantly reading and understanding the [JavaDocs for the classes being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvwkk.png). If you do that, it would be clear this will not work. There are (at least) 2 different ways this might be made to work. 1) Read the HTML using I/O and construct the content into a `String` for the `JLabel`. 2) Form the `String` into an `URL` and [create a `JEditorPane` using that URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mz3d.png).

Comment: BTW: What resources are you using that produced the above code? I ask because it is littered with problems (almost as many as there are lines of code). Both it, and whatever sources you're learning to use, should be put straight into the trash.